# Spring Security - authentication doesn't work properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've been struggling with authentication in my app which for some unknown for me reason is not working like it should. I know for sure that I pass correct username and password but still cannot be properly authenitcated by application.

Here's security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }  

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());  
        //auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin1").password("admin").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/account").hasRole("USER")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

User service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class UserService extends MainService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UserService.class);

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LOGGER.debug("Attempt to log in user with given username: " + login);

        User user = userRepository.findByAccountLogin(login);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with login: " + login + " does not exist");
        }

        LOGGER.debug("Loaded account: " + user.getAccount() + " password matches: " + new BCryptPasswordEncoder().matches("admin", user.getAccount().getPassword()));
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getAccount().getLogin(), user.getAccount().getPassword(), user.getAccount().getActivated(), true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user));
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(final User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for(AccountRole role : user.getAccount().getRoles()) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getId().getaRole().getType()));
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Granted authorities: " + grantedAuthorities);
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

}
```

This fragment of code ensures me that I've been passing proper data:

```
LOGGER.debug("Loaded account: " + user.getAccount() + " password matches: " + new BCryptPasswordEncoder().matches("admin", user.getAccount().getPassword()));
```

What can be a cause of that?

Comment: I am pretty new to spring myself so please forgive me if i make dumb suggestions, but i just built a (working) authentication myself so maybe i might help. I am configuring everything in XML so not sure if i understand that correctly, anyway your SimpleGrantedAuthorities are called something like "ROLE_USER", yet you permit "USER" for "/account". Or does it work that way?

Comment: Are your passwords actually stored encrypted in the database?

Comment: Yes, it's encrypted.